# How to integrate Okta SAML to an existing SPA (VueJS)

Tags: saml, okta

An existing Vue SPA is provided and the requirement is to integrate Okta SAML 2.0 to it. So, I got the following information from my client:

- Identity Provider Single Sign-On URL
- Identity Provider Issuer
- X.509 Certificate
- IDP metadata

Is it possible to integrate SAML to SPA? How the above information can help me to do the integration?

Comment: It would be much easier to integrate OIDC in a SPA app with [Okta's Vue SDK](https://github.com/okta/okta-vue). For SPA apps that require SAML, I recommend you do the authentication on your backend (if you have one).

Comment: @MattRaible Thanks for your answer. Yes, I do have a backend for the SPA. Cloud you please explain more about how to integrate SAML to my backend? I mean the user will be redirected to IDP login page, and the login result will then back to the backend via the callback route. So, how the backend can send back the login result to the SPA?